# Show/Hide Divs based on Radio Buttons with checked values coming from a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

how to Show/Hide Divs based on Radio Buttons with checked values coming from a database i am using php and sql

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Ongoing" checked="checked">Ongoing<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Comming">Comming<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="End">End<br>

<div>div for ongoing</div>
<div>div for Comming</div>
<div>div for End</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to try and resolve this yourself? Your question is broad and unclear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes. but not working. i want if i store data ongoing in database then first div show. if i store data coming then second div show

Answer (score 1):

The following could be helpful to solve your issue (please note the usage of *data-** attribute in the div element):

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('[name=status]');
radio.forEach(r => r.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var v = this.value;
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(d => {
    if (d.getAttribute('data-value') == v){
      d.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
      d.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}));
```

```css
[data-value = "Comming"],[data-value = "End"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Ongoing" checked="checked">Ongoing<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Comming">Comming<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="End">End<br>

<div data-value="Ongoing">div for ongoing</div>
<div data-value="Comming">div for Comming</div>
<div data-value="End">div for End</div>
```